# How to show the text value visible in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to visible the paragraph `modalBody` but its diplaying none in page. i don't know what is wrong here

```js
socket.on("room_not_found", async (providerName) => {
  document.getElementById("modalHeader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("modalBody").style.visibility = "visible";
});

async function intiateVideoCall() {
  providerName = getProviderName().replace("/customer/", "");
  socket.emit("customer_join", providerName);
}
```

```html
<div id="modalHeader">
  <p className="msg">Customer Details</p>
  <div className="buttonValue">
    <input
      className="btn-login"
      type="submit"
      id="button"
      onClick="{intiateVideoCall}"
      value="Connect"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modalBody">
  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: display and visibility are two different things

Comment: Take a loot at the `#modalBody p` initial styles. What its `display` value? Also look for `opacity` or else.

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: this things looks like it can be solvable with [<details>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

Comment: did you call the function?    "showModal() "

Comment: even if you call `showModal()` you still hide it using `display = 'none'` so visibility have no effect - you should set the `display = "block"`

Answer (score 2):

`visibility: hidden`, means that your element is not visible, (like opacity: 0) but still exists, have a width a height and clips with other elements

However `display: none` means your element is not displayed and it don't occupy space at all.

Should also mention that, if you have `display: none` in a element and you add `visibiliy: 'visible'` it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add to your question a minimal reproducible example to show us how you use your code, because I use your code with a button to activate your `showModal()` function and I think it works the way you want it to work

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("modalHeader").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("modalBody").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   
    <div id="modalHeader">
         <p className='msg'>Customer Details</p> 
      </div>   

     <div id="modalBody">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you. Are you sure that `socket.on` is called ?

Comment: yes it is calling , because here `modalHeader` is displaying none but here `modalbody` is also displaying none

Comment: i replaced with `document.getElementById("modalBody").style.display= "block";` and it worked!

Comment: Oh nice. So edit again your question with this time at the end something like: SOLUTION: I change ... and it works